# IPC synchronization issue while reading & writing into shared files

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, synchronization, ipc

The following code is called from several simultaneously running processes, while accessing a group of shared files. These files contain a list of *entries*. (The reason I mention files *(pl.)* is only because the actual list with *entries* is broken down into smaller files on disk.)

The stipulation is that each *entry* must have a unique auto-incremented ID. For that I'm implementing a named mutex for file access synchronization, but evidently I'm still missing something, since sometimes I am getting repeating or duplicate IDs (the `dwUniqueID` variable below) in those *entries*.

Can someone suggest why?

Next is the brief code, with all error checks omitted for brevity. I also stripped it down to bare API calls:

```
//Global variables
HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
HANDLE hMutex = NULL;
```

then the initialization (done once):

```
//INFO: Error checks are omitted for brevity!

PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psdMutex = NULL;
::ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
    L"D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)S:(ML;;;;;S-1-16-0)",
    SDDL_REVISION_1, &psdMutex, NULL);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = psdMutex;

//Create global IPC mutex
hMutex = ::CreateMutex(&sa, FALSE, L"Global\\My_IPC_Mutex_Name");

::LocalFree(psdMutex);
```

then one of the needed files is opened for the first time as such:

```
//INFO: Error checks are omitted for brevity!

//Open initial file
ReopenFile();

void ReopenFile()
{
    //Close previous file
    if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ::FlushFileBuffers(hFile);
        ::CloseHandle(hFile);
        hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;   
    }

    //Create/open file
    hFile = ::CreateFile(strFilePath, 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH,
        NULL);
}
```

and then, just to test my IPC synchronization, I'm calling the following code in a long loop:

```
//INFO: Error checks are omitted for brevity!
for(;;){

//Enter IPC critical section
if(::WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE) ==  WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    //Read last DWORD from file
    DWORD dwUniqueID = 0, ncbWrtn;

    LARGE_INTEGER liFileSz = {0};
    ::GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &liFileSz);
    if(liFileSz.QuadPart >= sizeof(DWORD))
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER li0;
        li0.QuadPart = -(LONGLONG)(sizeof(DWORD));
        ::SetFilePointerEx(hFile, li0, NULL, FILE_END);

        ::ReadFile(hFile, &dwUniqueID, sizeof(DWORD), &ncbWrtn, NULL);
    }

    //Do other work
    //...

    if(CheckIfThisFileIsFull(liFileSz))
    {
        //File must be closed and another one opened
        ReopenFile();
    }

    //Increment unique ID
    dwUniqueID++;

    //And write it into file
    LARGE_INTEGER li1 = {0};
    ::SetFilePointerEx(hFile, li1, NULL, FILE_END);
    ::WriteFile(hFile, &dwUniqueID, sizeof(DWORD), &ncbWrtn, NULL);

    //Flush file
    ::FlushFileBuffers(hFile);

    //Leave IPC critical section
    ::ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
}
else break;

}
```

Comment: It might be more sensible to use file locking (LockFile, etc.) rather than a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN documentation for [FlushFileBuffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) leads me to believe that Windows is still allowed to cache the write operation and therefor the file is not guaranteed to be consistent with other processes when your mutex is released.

Comment: You could try adding the unbuffered flag `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` to `CreateFile`, using shared memory, or a shared memory mapped file. That's the order I would go about it at least.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag as well. Unfortunately it's not easy to use. One needs to align writes on a sector size on disk and page size in RAM. It opens too much potential for failure.

Comment: No, if you call `FlushFileBuffers` that guarantees that all other processes will see the data immediately.  It might not guarantee that the data will be safe if the machine loses power, however.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer to my own question. The reason I was getting duplicate IDs was because of the faulty logic of my implementation: When my `CheckIfThisFileIsFull()` method determined that the current file was full it would come up with a new file and then `ReopenFile()` would open and start using it. Well, this did not work if more than one process were using this method. For instance, if one process was still holding the old file, while another process already created a new file, the first process will not know about it and thus reuse the old ID and create a duplicate.

Anyway, I appreciate your input... if you remove my `ReopenFile()` from the `for(;;)` loop in my original post, my implementation will hold for multi-process application (i.e. no additional locks are needed.)